# Unable to make put request using node js. Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, http, mongoose, put

i am just looking to make an PUT request using Mongoose database. But Its Unable to make any request. I am using postman to pass the data, but no response.

script.js

```
app.route("/articles/:articleTitle")
    .put(function (req, res) {
        Article.updateMany(
            { title: req.params.articleTitle },
            { title: req.body.title, content: req.body.content },
            { overwrite: true },
            function (err) {
                if (!err) {
                    res.send("Successfully Updated The Data !");
                }
            }
        );
    });
```

here is the code i am using to pass the PUT request in my localhost server but unable to do so.

[No Response Here Is The Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yvXfD.png)

Answer (score 2):

You don't send any response in case of an error, causing the request to hang and never return. Change it to e.g.:

```
function (err) {
    if (!err) {
        res.send("Successfully Updated The Data !");
    } else {
      console.log(err);
      res.status(500).send("Update failed due to error " + err.message);
    }  
}
```

Comment: This is the correct implementation.

Answer (score 0):

```
app.route("/articles/:articleTitle")
    .put(async function (req, res) {
        try {
            await Article.updateMany(
                { title: req.params.articleTitle },
                { title: req.body.title, content: req.body.content },
                { overwrite: true },
            )
            res.status(200).send("Successfully Updated The Data !");
        } catch (err) {
            res.status(500).send("Update failed due to error " + err.message);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
.put(function (req, res) {
    Article.updateMany(
      { title: req.params.articleTitle },
      { title: req.body.title, content: req.body.content }
    )
      .then(function (articles) {
        res.send(articles);
      })
      .catch(function (err) {
        res.send(err);
      });
  });
```